# Latex rendering in IE7

Tags: support, math-display

I'm using IE7 (forced to by corporate policy unfortunately) and do not get any of the Latex rendered in questions. MathJax seems to work when I visit its home page, is that what is used on this site now?

Do I need to do something to enable the rendering here?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using IE8 and have similar problems.  I have to update the screen in "compatibility view" (the little green button to the right of where the url's are displayed).

Sometimes it will replace all MathJax entries with [Math Processing Error].   When that happens, I close down IE8 and restart it, and try again.

Also, under Tools, under Compatibility View Settings, I have experimented with adding/deleting certain websites that show up as "compatible" by default.   Sometimes it helps, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Internet Options - Security tab - Internet zone - Custom Level...
ActiveX controls and plug-ins

- Allow Scriptlets (ENABLE)

Comment: That didn't work. I can get equations to displayon the MathJax homepage, so was wondering if it was a SE setting I needed to change.